# Converting PSI to Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, unit-conversion

The question I'm asking is pretty much:

How do you convert PSI to Velocity?

Everywhere I look it says `You can't`, but can you?

And what would you need to know to do so if there is no direct way to convert?

My homework is to convert 0.14 PSI into m/s.

**EDIT** Sorry guys my teacher does like being tricky, no clue why. Sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused.

Comment: How do you convert seconds to kilograms?

Comment: What is the point of that question? @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld What on Earth does pressure have to do with velocity?

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld Why do you even want to?

Comment: I was told to change 0.14 PSI into m/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away from the European currency systems](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html).

The answer to your question is simply **you don't**. Just as converting seconds to kilograms, or pounds to yards/hour isn't feasible what you asked is also not possible.

Pressure and velocity measure different things, so it's illogical to convert one into another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have no clue. Our teacher does like being tricky, so maybe this is why. Thanks for your help. @BernardMeurer

Answer (score 1):

V=m/s
P=F/A
P=(mass*v/s)/s
So how could you interchange them they are not same quantaties ya you would link them by just opening force formula .