# Conversion between pressure in PSI and velocity

Tags: pressure, velocity, flow, speed, bernoulli-equation

My question is about whether you can convert the pressure something has to the velocity it will have. For example, if I had water shooting out of a hose at 100PSI, could I calculate the speed that the water would have after it leaves the hose? Is that possible to calculate with just pressure, or would you need more information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting PSI to Velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242473/)

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli's principle should give you $p=\rho v^2/2$, where $\rho$ is the water density. I'm just not sure about the range of applicability since it is derived for incompressible liquid (where water is just fine) and steady flow. The latter might depend, for instance, on the shape of the hose output. Anyway, this is probably a decent approximation.